# Getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" when fetching random posts from a subreddit

Tags: json, discord.js, node-fetch

When I try to fetch a post from `https://www.reddit.com/r/hoodironycentral/random/.json` it returns me undefined while `JSON.parse` is running.

Here is my code:

```js
import { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export default {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("hoodclassic")
      .setDescription("haha so funny"),
      run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
    const response = await fetch('https://reddit.com/r/hoodironycentral/random/.json');
        const data = await response.json();

            const [list] = JSON.parse(data.body);
            const [post] = list.data.children;

            const permalink = post.data.permalink;
            const memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            const memeImage = post.data.url;
            const memeTitle = post.data.title;
            const memeUpvotes = post.data.ups;
            const memeNumComments = post.data.num_comments;

            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`);
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`);
            embed.setColor('Random');
            embed.setImage(memeImage);
            embed.setFooter({
                text:` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`
            });

            channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }};
```

Here is the console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (file:///C:/x/v44bot/src/commands/reddit.js:13:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

TL;DR: I am trying to fetch a post from reddit, but it returns undefined.

Comment: Why do you want to parse `data`? You've already converted it to an object at `const data = await response.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are trying to convert an already converted object, try this code

```
import { EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

export default {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("hoodclassic")
      .setDescription("haha so funny"),
      run: async (client, interaction) => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
    const response = await fetch('https://reddit.com/r/hoodironycentral/random/.json');
        const data = await response.json();

            const [post] = data.data.children;

            const permalink = post.data.permalink;
            const memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            const memeImage = post.data.url;
            const memeTitle = post.data.title;
            const memeUpvotes = post.data.ups;
            const memeNumComments = post.data.num_comments;

            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`);
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`);
            embed.setColor('Random');
            embed.setImage(memeImage);
            embed.setFooter({
                text:` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`
            });

            channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
        }};
```

Comment: thank you, but it now throws me `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')` at data.data.children, thats probably about the reddits side, right?